# Write specific data in one cell depending on contents of another cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Pandas newbie and I have a csv file with about 50 different columns. Some of them contain a "-1" value and the last column I have named "Holder" to store the results of some comparisons I make on the other columns.

Data is of the form

```
Row 1:
Investments_Cash  Holder
0                    NaN

Row 2:
Investments_Cash  Holder
0                    NaN

Row 3:
Investments_Cash  Holder
-1                   NaN
```

For the rows that contain "Investments_Cash" of -1, I want to set the corresponding "Holder" column value to "Found". How can I do this?

I've tried

```
if df.Investments_Cash == -1:
    df.Holder = "Found"
```

but I get an error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: try this: `df.ix[df.Investments_Cash == -1, 'Holder'] = 'Found'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.Investments_Cash == -1, 'Holder'] = 'Found'
```